# Any way to remove warning message in Ranorex report "This control (from process 'saplogon') seems to be a Windows Forms control..."

Tags: c#, sap-gui, ranorex

I'm using Ranorex 6.2 (Ranorex is Automated Software Testing Tool using C# as program language) and every time, my automation test report will have below warning.

```
This control (from process 'saplogon') seems to be a Windows Forms control, but was not recognized as such, possibly due to a security limitation. UI element identification capabilities for this control may be limited.
If this control is a WinForms control, please make sure that the automating process has the rights to access the automated application. Otherwise, please ignore this limitation.
Process: 'saplogon' (pid 6640)
The following website provides more information on this technology limitation:
http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/technology-instrumentation/general-troubleshooting.html#c3250
(This message is only shown once per report.)
```

Though it provides the URL, I still can not get ride of this warning.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can't really remember how to disable those messages in the report (if even possible at all - though with custom logging it can be achieved). But i suggest you just enable sciprting in SAP GUI. Then Ranorex will recognize it as it should.

Comment: https://www.ranorex.com/help/latest/technology-instrumentation/testing-of-sap-applications for enabling it on client side.

You might have to create a global parameter as well but can't remember if it is a must when only using SAP GUI. It's more related to webDynpro testing. But to get a lot of information regarding this go the Ranorex forum, find my account (Martin) and go through the SAP related posts.

Also remember to run SAP GUI (AUT) with the same priviledges as Ranorex is running. So either both have been run with admin priviledges or neither of them have.

Comment: the scripting is already enabled, and both SAP and Ranorex are running elevated.